# Не сохраняется сессия в node.js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, cors, express-sessions

Приложение на node js, используется сервер express. К express подключено использование сессий:

```
const express = require('express');
const session = require('express-session')

const app = express();

app.use(
  session({
    secret: "secret",        
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: true,
  })
);
```

Пробуем в сессии сохранить какое-либо значение:

```
router.post('/', function(req, res, next)
{
    console.log("req.session.test: ", req.session.test);

    req.session.test = "test";
    req.session.save();
}
```

Почему-то сессия при повторном запросе не сохраняется, т.е. req.session.test - undefined.

Так же используется cors:

```
const cors = require("cors");
app.use(cors());
```

Что делаем не так?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема может быть решена одним из способов:

1. Использованием браузера отличного от Chrome/Chromium.
2. Работой по безопасному протоколу.
3. Отправкой запросов на хост localhost